# Looking for time-series grid data set

Tags: transmission-line, data, power-grid

The electric power grid consists of many buses, with generators and loads connected to each bus.

The so-called *operating point* of the system consists of the voltage magnitudes, Vn, and voltage phase angles, An, at every bus n. So, the operating point of a system with N buses is the collection of operating points over all buses, (V,A) = ((V1,A1),(V2,A2),...,(VN,AN)).

I am wondering if anyone knows of any public data sets that shows the operating point of the system over time, for example, in hourly increments, over multiple days. If this is not available, I can reconstruct it given the generation/demand at each bus (although not ideal).

Comment: What is the problem with taking IEEE standard system (say 9 bus or 14 bus) and simulate it for a time series demand (perunitized data set) that you want?

Comment: @Hazem Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure I understand. For a power flow analysis, one needs to specify not only demand but also generation. How would I specify consistent values of generation and demand. Is there hourly data for this anywhere for the IEEE test cases?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you will not find such information. However, you can mimic the reality. In conventional power systems, load dispatch centers perform economic dispatch/optimum power flow to distribute the expected load among the power plant. Based on this fact,

1) You can take IEEE system, with per-unitized demand data.

2) Perform economic dispatch (or optimum power flow) to specify the power plants generation.

3) Now you have generation and load time series, you can run load flow for every sample to get (V,A) time series.

You may need the cost function of the generation units to perform the economic dispatch, there are many research papers where you can find such information for these generation units. See [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1198323/) and [this](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/1216163/) for example. Moreover, You may need also demand time series, you may download it from [here](http://sites.ieee.org/pes-iss/data-sets/).

One more point, the previous information get closer to reality in countries where conventional power systems are still there. However, in restructured power systems, the energy market plays the main role in dispatching the generators.